# VBA messing my structured reference in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this site but been using VBA for few years now. I have a problem which has started only recently and is quite inconsistent and appears on my PC with Office 365 but not on laptop running MS Office Pro 2016.

The problem I have is that when the formula is inserted into the worksheet, it changes the structured reference from column *"DesktopObs[Class Title]"* to a cell *"DesktopObs[@[Class Title]]"*.

I am getting this in the column:
`=MAX(IF(DesktopObs[@[Class Title]]=[@[Class Title]],IF(DesktopObs[@[Observation Type]]<>"Re-Obs",DesktopObs[Actual Observation date])))`

While I should be getting this:
`=MAX(IF(DesktopObs[Class Title]=[@[Class Title]],IF(DesktopObs[Observation Type]<>"Re-Obs",DesktopObs[Actual Observation date])))`

Below is the (part of) code I use for 'Restore Formulas'.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Class Setup")
Set rng = ws.Range("tbl_ClassSetup[Latest Desktop Observation]")


Call f_WorksheetProtection(ws, False)

strFormula(1) = "=MAX(IF(DesktopObs[Class Title DO]=[@[Class Title]],IF(DesktopObs[Observation Type]<>""Re-Obs"",DesktopObs[Actual Observation date])))"
strFormula(2) = "=MAX(IF(DesktopObs[Class Title]=[@[Class Title]],IF(DesktopObs[Observation Type]=""Re-Obs"",DesktopObs[Actual Observation date])))"


For i = 1 To 2
  rng.Offset(0, i - 1).Formula = strFormula(i)
  rng.Offset(0, i - 1).FormulaArray = rng.Offset(0, i - 1).Formula
Next i
```

I suspect it has something to do with Office 365 (possibly AutoCorrect) but have not been able to identify what exactly it is. I have even tried and re-installed Windows and whole office from scratch, but this problem still occurs.

Comment: Try entering the formula as the `.Value` property rather than the `.Formula` property.

Comment: Changing the .Formula property to .Value property made the trick! Many thanks for your help!!! ;-)

Comment: Having done some more research, it seems the **correct** method of handling this is by using the`.Formula2` property.  See [.Formula vs .Formula2 Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2)